# Scale python kivy line

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to plot various line segments using kivy. The line appears really small (at one end of the screen) and I would like to scale it up. Ideally, I would like to specify coordinates from the center of screen and specify width and height so that the line segments appear well. Here is the code I wrote:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line

class MyWidget(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            for obstacle in obstacles:
                print obstacle
                Line(points=[20, 5, 40, 5],width=1)
            pass
            # add your instruction for main canvas here

class MotionPlanningApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=5, spacing=1)
        root.add_widget(MyWidget())
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MotionPlanningApp().run()
```

Is there some way to do this in kivy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Translate instructions to move the line (effectively moving the origin of the canvas) and Scale instructions to stretch it.

For instance, you could have:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
with self.canvas:
    self.translate = Translate(Window.width / 2, Window.height / 2.)
```

You would also need to modify the translate instruction later if the window size changed, by binding a function to that.

Regardless, though, the coordinates are in screen pixels so the line is currently small just because you only made it 20 pixels long.